# Method call not executing

Tags: android

I have an Android Activity called Activity A shown below. When I click on the saveButton, the saveData() method is called and then the finish() method gets called and closes Activity A. When I click on the triggerActivity_B button in Activity A to go to Activity B and then click on the triggerActivity_A button in Activity B to go back to Activity A, I click on the saveButton and the saveData() method doesn't get called, just the finish() method gets called. It only seems to execute when I don't leave the Activity, I'm not sure why this is.

Your help would be most appreciated.

**ActivityA.java**:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveData();
                finish();
            }
        });

        triggerActivity_B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveData() {
        String desc = descriptionEntry.getText().toString();

       if (mRowId == null) {
           long id = mDbHelper2.createDescription(desc);
           if (id > 0) {
               mRowId = id;
           }
       } else {
           mDbHelper2.updateDescription(mRowId, desc);
       }
    }
}
```

**ActivityB.java**:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        triggerActivity_A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: first, check out your old questions and give some feedback in the form of accepting answers, or add your own answer if the correct one wasn't igven, and accept that. 0% is a bit lowish. Secondly: are you it isn't called? couldn't it be that the second activity A just doesn't have anything to save? did you put a `Log.d` in that method?

Comment: Can you please show the code for `saveData()`?

Comment: Thank you - can you please add a Log.d() in your saveData() function to see if it's actually being called or not? You can use this: `Log.d("DEBUG", "Yep, it's being called")`. Check the LogCat for the "DEBUG" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Point is if you click on the triggerActivity_A button in ActivityB, a new instance of ActivityA is being made; it doesn't go back to your first ActivityA and thus probably has nothing to save.

Also note that your first activityA seizes to exist when you push the button to open ActivityB, as you are calling finish(). If you want to keep the first ActivityA don't call finish(), and don't start a new activity when pressing the button in ActivityB, just call finish() only).

There is no reason to assume saveData() isn't called.

And do please improve your acceptrate.